# Calculating Minimum Edit Distance for unequal strings python

Tags: python, nlp, edit-distance

I am trying to implement Minimum Edit Distance with the substitution cost of 2. Following is the code I've so far. It works well for strings of equal length but generates error for the unequal strings. Kindly correct me where i am wrong

```
def med(source, target):
#     if len(x) > len(y):
#         print("insode if")
#         source, target = y, x
print(len(source), len(target))
cost = [[0 for inner in range(len(source)+1)] for outer in 
range(len(target)+1)]

global backtrace 
backtrace = [[0 for inner in range(len(source)+1)] for outer in 
range(len(target)+1)]
global SUB
global INS
global DEL

for i in range(0,len(target)+1):
    cost[i][0] = i

for j in range(0,len(source)+1):
    cost[0][j] = j

for i in range(1,len(target)+1):
    for j in range(1,len(source)+1):
        if source[i-1]==target[j-1]:
            cost[i][j] = cost[i-1][j-1] 
        else:
            deletion = cost[i-1][j]+1
            insertion = cost[i][j-1]+1
            substitution = cost[i-1][j-1]+2
            cost[i][j] = min(insertion,deletion,substitution)

            if cost[i][j] == substitution:
                backtrace[i][j] = SUB
            elif cost[i][j] == insertion:
                backtrace[i][j] = INS
            else:
                backtrace[i][j] = DEL


return cost[i][j]

med("levenshtein","levels")
```

The error i get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-86bf20ea27c7> in <module>()
 49     return cost[i][j]
 50 
---> 51 med("levenshtein","levels")

<ipython-input-26-86bf20ea27c7> in med(source, target)
 31     for i in range(1,len(target)+1):
 32         for j in range(1,len(source)+1):
---> 33             if source[i-1]==target[j-1]:
 34                 cost[i][j] = cost[i-1][j-1]
 35             else:

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For different length strings, `cost` and `backtrace` indices doesn't match.

Can be implemented minimum edit distance with 2 substitution cost by updating only one numpy `m` * `n` arr with cost at each step.

[image]

As per Algorithm,
Below code will do the job.

```py
def minimumEditDistance(first, second): 
    
    #Creating numpy ndarray( initialized with 0 of dimension of size of both strings
    
    matrix = np.zeros((len(first)+1,len(second)+1), dtype=np.int)
    
    
    # Cross relation loop through each character of each string with each other and
    # fill the respective index of matrxi (row,column)
    
    for i in range(len(first)+1): 
        for j in range(len(second)+1): 
            
            #First doing the boundary value analysis, if first or second string is empty so directly adding insertion cost
            if i == 0:  
                matrix[i][j] = j  
            #Second case
            elif j == 0: 
                matrix[i][j] = i
            else: 
                matrix[i][j] = min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1,  
                                   matrix[i-1][j] + 1,        
                                   matrix[i-1][j-1] + 2 if first[i-1] != second[j-1] else matrix[i-1][j-1] + 0)     
                                   # Adjusted the cost accordinly, insertion = 1, deletion=1 and substitution=2
    return matrix[len(first)][len(second)]  # Returning the final
```

## Output:

```
>>>print(minimumEditDistance('levenshtein','levels'))
7
>>>print(minimumEditDistance('levenshtein','levenshtein'))
0
```